# D3D11 Indices are Messed Up and Doesn't Follow my Primitive Topology

Tags: directx11, vertex

I am attempting to create a cube but I have been stuck on this for a very long time to no avail.

My results look like this:

[image: Very sad result]

All of my indices are messed up! Some are connected to the wrong vertices and most weirdly the light blue vertex is alone; it isn't a complete triangle.

Here is my initialization function:

```
swap_chain_description.BufferDesc.Width = 0; // Figure it out yourself
swap_chain_description.BufferDesc.Height = 0;
swap_chain_description.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM; // Layout of pixels
swap_chain_description.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0; // Pick whatever is already there
swap_chain_description.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 0; // Pick whatever is already there
swap_chain_description.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING::DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED; // Don't need scaling
swap_chain_description.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER::DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED; // Scanline order (Interlaced, etc)
swap_chain_description.SampleDesc.Count = 1; // No anti-aliasing
swap_chain_description.SampleDesc.Quality = 0; // No anti-aliasing
swap_chain_description.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT; // Use buffer as render target
swap_chain_description.BufferCount = 1; // One back buffer
swap_chain_description.OutputWindow = window; // Use this window
swap_chain_description.Windowed = true; // We want it windowed
swap_chain_description.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT::DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD; // Swap effect that usually has the best performance
swap_chain_description.Flags = 0u; // No flags

D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
    nullptr, // Choose default adapter
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE::D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, // Use hardware device
    nullptr, // Handle to driver
    0, // No flags
    nullptr, // Give us any feature level
    0,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION, // Default SDK Version
    &swap_chain_description, // Swap chain description
    &swap_chain, // Swap Chain
    &device, // Device
    nullptr, // Output pointer - Sets to feature level
    &context // Context
);

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> back_buffer = nullptr;
swap_chain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Resource), &back_buffer);
device->CreateRenderTargetView(
    back_buffer.Get(),
    nullptr,
    &target
);

// Create depth stencil state
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depth_stencil_description = {};
depth_stencil_description.DepthEnable = true;
depth_stencil_description.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depth_stencil_description.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11DepthStencilState> depth_stencil_state;
device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depth_stencil_description, &depth_stencil_state);

// Bind depth state
context->OMSetDepthStencilState(depth_stencil_state.Get(), 1u);

//Create depth stencil texture
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> depth_stencil;
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc_depth = { };
desc_depth.Width = 800u;
desc_depth.Height = 600u;
desc_depth.MipLevels = 1u;
desc_depth.ArraySize = 1u;
desc_depth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
desc_depth.SampleDesc.Count = 1u;
desc_depth.SampleDesc.Quality = 0u;
desc_depth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE::D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
desc_depth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_FLAG::D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
device->CreateTexture2D(&desc_depth, nullptr, &depth_stencil);

// Create depth stensil state
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC descDSV = { };
descDSV.Format = DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION::D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
descDSV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0u;
device->CreateDepthStencilView(depth_stencil.Get(), &descDSV, &depth_stencil_view);

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11RasterizerState> rasterizer_state = nullptr;
D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterizer_state_description = { };
rasterizer_state_description.FillMode = fill_mode;
rasterizer_state_description.CullMode = cull_mode;
rasterizer_state_description.FrontCounterClockwise = true;
rasterizer_state_description.DepthBias = false;
rasterizer_state_description.DepthBiasClamp = 0;
rasterizer_state_description.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0;
rasterizer_state_description.DepthClipEnable = true;
rasterizer_state_description.ScissorEnable = false;
rasterizer_state_description.MultisampleEnable = false;
rasterizer_state_description.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
HANDLE_POSSIBLE_EXCEPTION(device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterizer_state_description, rasterizer_state.GetAddressOf()));

context->RSSetState(rasterizer_state.Get());

// Configure Viewport
viewport.Width = 800u;
viewport.Height = 600u;
viewport.MinDepth = 0;
viewport.MaxDepth = 1;
viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
context->RSSetViewports(1u, &viewport);

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11BlendState> blend_state = nullptr;
D3D11_BLEND_DESC blend_description = {};
ZeroMemory(&blend_description, sizeof(D3D11_BLEND_DESC));
blend_description.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = true;
blend_description.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND::D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
blend_description.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND::D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
blend_description.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP::D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blend_description.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND::D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blend_description.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND::D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
blend_description.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP::D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blend_description.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE::D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
device->CreateBlendState(&blend_description, &blend_state);

context->OMSetBlendState(blend_state.Get(), 0, 0xffffffff);

// Set Primitive Topology to triangle list
set_primitive_topology(primitive_topology);

context->OMSetRenderTargets(1u, target.GetAddressOf(), depth_stencil_view.Get());
```

My primitive topology is set to `D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST`, which is why I'm confused about why there is that uncompleted triangle in the result.

This is my draw function:

```
set_vertex_buffer(object);
set_index_buffer(object);

/* I don't think the shader and constant buffer business matters so I didn't include it here, it's here though */

// Draw it
context->DrawIndexed((UINT)object.appearance.mesh.indices.size(), 0u, 0u);
```

Setting my index and vertex buffers is straight-forward:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> vertex_buffer = nullptr;

// Buffer Description (Vertex)
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC buffer_description = {  };
buffer_description.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
buffer_description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
buffer_description.CPUAccessFlags = 0u;
buffer_description.MiscFlags = 0u;
buffer_description.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * object.appearance.mesh.vertices.size();
buffer_description.StructureByteStride = sizeof(Vertex);
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data = {  };
data.pSysMem = &object.appearance.mesh.vertices[0];

// Creating the Buffer
device->CreateBuffer(&buffer_description, &data, &vertex_buffer);

// Bind Vertex Buffer to Pipeline
UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
UINT offset = 0u;
context->IASetVertexBuffers(0u, 1u, vertex_buffer.GetAddressOf(), &stride, &offset);
```

and

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> index_buffer;
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC index_buffer_description = { };
index_buffer_description.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
index_buffer_description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
index_buffer_description.CPUAccessFlags = 0u;
index_buffer_description.MiscFlags = 0u;
index_buffer_description.ByteWidth = sizeof(USHORT) * object.appearance.mesh.indices.size();
index_buffer_description.StructureByteStride = sizeof(USHORT);
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subresource_data = { };
subresource_data.pSysMem = &object.appearance.mesh.indices[0];
device->CreateBuffer(&index_buffer_description, &subresource_data, &index_buffer);
// Bind index buffer
context->IASetIndexBuffer(index_buffer.Get(), DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0u);
```

Here is where I'm initializing my vertices and indices, I also drew them out:

```
Mesh mesh = {
     {
        {-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 255, 0, 0, 255},
        { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 255, 0, 255 },
        { -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0, 255, 255 },
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 255, 0, 255, 255 },
        { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 255, 255, 0, 255 },
        { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 255, 255, 255 },
        { -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 255, 0, 0, 255 },
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 255, 0, 255 }
    },
    {
        0u, 2u, 1u, 2u, 3u, 1u,
        1u, 3u, 5u, 3u, 7u, 5u,
        2u, 6u, 3u, 3u, 6u, 7u,
        4u, 5u, 7u, 4u, 7u, 6u,
        0u, 4u, 2u, 2u, 4u, 6u,
        0u, 1u, 4u, 1u, 5u, 4u,
    }
};
```

[image: my epic drawing]

I do not change my primitive topology anywhere else than the places I showed.

Please ask me anything about my code if you need to, I am very confused about why my code is doing this.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are missing an input layout to tell dx11 how your vertex data is ordered. Might have missed it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are using 16-bit indices in your call:

```
context->IASetIndexBuffer(index_buffer.Get(), DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0u);
```

Thus, all your index data on CPU must be 16-bit also (unsigned **short** instead of unsigned *int*).

If you'd rather want to keep the indices on CPU 32 bit, just change it to DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing my indices from UINTs to USHORTs.

I'm not sure why this fixes it but it does.

Such pretty cubes :)
[image]